# Sprite.Frame.Contains in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

So I need to do this simple line of code in my game. It is currently in swift and I am trying to convert it to Objective-C and I got stuck as in Objective C there is no

> sprite.frame.cointains(//CGPOINT);

I am wondering how can I go ahead and do this as it is vital for my game. 
Here's the code in swift

```
    if fruitNode.frame.contains(location!) {
        touchPoint = location!
        touching = true
    }
```

If anybody can help me to respond that will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: In SpriteKit, you could just use `[fruitNode containsPoint:location]` in Obj-C

Comment: However if you did want to check if a CGRect - which is what the frame is - contains a point you would use `CGRectContainsPoint(fruitNode.frame,location);` - but worthwhile to check out reference at - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint

Comment: Oh thats great @prototypical! By any chance would you know how to convert this? `let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
         let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-fruitNode.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-fruitNode.position.y)
         let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
         fruitNode.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity`

Comment: Sure, if you want to hire me to convert your app to Objective-C. That's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: what do you mean by hiring you?

Comment: It means that this is a Q&A site. It is not about converting your code line by line. Programmers get paid to do this sort of thing, if you aren't interested in learning and applying. Reference in my answer is what a programmer would use to learn how to convert his code from swift to obj-c. But sure... check email in my profile, if you want to hire me to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective C you could do this using `SKNode` method:

```
if ([fruitNode containsPoint:location])
{
   // do this
}
```

or if you needed to use `CGRect` for some reason :

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(fruitNode.frame, location))
{
  // do this
}
```

definitely check out the Apple reference for `CGRectContainsPoint` - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint

Comment: I'd stick with containsPoint since it could be overridden in a subclass to do something other than return CGRectContainsPoint (for example a circle sprite might fail points within the frame but outside the radius of the circle).

Comment: agreed. I mostly added it because I thought he might be confused about `CGRect` having a method `containsPoint` and wanted to clarify.